# Upgrading and hybridizing a broken SharePoint 2013 installation

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, workflow, upgrade, hybrid-solution

I'm currently working on a roadmap to update our  botched SP 2013 installation to SP 2019 Hybrid.

The installation contains a large number of non-critical SharePoint solutions as well as a number of critical 2013 and 2010 workflows that we are mostly not able to edit or recreate because my predecessor did not demand the source code from the implementation company and our 2010 workflows are not editable with SharePoint Designer because they were deployed as solutions.

I'm unsure about the logical first step for this project.
Would it be better to first upgrade to SP 2019 (and probably break most of the workflows because of hardcoded version dependencies, etc.) or implement hybrid first, move the critical sites to the cloud, recreate workflows in MS Flows and upgrade after that?

Comment: What is "SharePoint Editor"? SP2010 workflows can be edited with SharePoint Designer, which is free to download.

Comment: I meant Designer. In this case our 2010 workflows have been written and deployed as solution packages in Visual Studio. We are unable to edit them in SP Designer and can not unpack the solutions. Also as mentioned: No Source Code.

Comment: So the workflows are not editable because they were deployed as a solution, not because they are 2010 workflows. These details matter.

Comment: Yes. I changed my question to reflect that fact.